# Eclipse Error: java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting a error trying to compile a simple code in Eclipse. I'm using jre8.

For example, when I try to compile this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyProject {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myList.add("test");
        myList.add("test2");

        Collections.sort(myList);
    }
}
```

I get a error in the `Collections.sort(myList);` line.

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

    at project.Principal.main(Principal.java:14)
```

I have already opened eclipse Build Path, removed JRE System Library [jre8] and added it again. But didn't work! What can I do? Thanks!

PS.: In the `Collections.sort(myList);` line eclipse shows this error:

**The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is inderectly referenced from required .class files.**

Comment: What JDK are u using?

Comment: jdk1.8.0_05 (directly from folder)

Comment: Have you tried creating a new workspace?

Comment: What's your Eclipse version? See [How to set eclipse with JRE 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150755/how-to-set-eclipse-with-jre-8).

Comment: What compliance level do you have set for Java in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301986/the-type-java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-package-declaration)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Ensure that your Eclipse IDE supports Java 8:

The first Eclipse version supporting Java 8 was Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2) with an additional patch. (See: [Installing Java™ 8 Support in Eclipse Kepler SR2](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/add-java-8-support-to-eclipse-kepler/), and the corresponding Marketplace Item that needs to be installed: [Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-8-support-eclipse-kepler-sr2)).

In my opinion you should udpate to the [latest Eclipse Version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

With Luna SR2 (4.4.2) no additional patch is necessary.

---

## Ensure the 1.8 JRE is available in your Workspace:

Windows > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs

[image: Installed JREs]

If this is not the case you can add a new JRE with the add button.

---

## Ensure that `JRE System Library` == `JavaSE-1.8` for your Project

In the Package Explorer, you should see the Java version:

[image: Package Explorer]

If this is not correct you should open the context menu the `JRE System Library` item and select the `Properties` menu entry.

[image: JRE System Library - Properties]

In your project you have a `.classpath` file (Use the `Navigator View` if you do not see the file), that should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

---

## Rebuild your project

Project Menu > Clean...

Select your project from the list or "Clean all projects" and "Start a build immediately"

---

See also:

- Explaination from @mkrakhin in his answer: [The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved in package declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24302496/91497)

Comment: This is an old question, but I will mark your answer as the correct to help other people. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am having the same problem. But my eclipse is using the jre1.8.0.45. But I am still facing the problem with 'StringBuilder' or a 'StringBuffer' class.

Comment: "you should open the context menu the JRE System Library item and select the Properties menu entry" how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the BytecodeParser class in soot.JastAddJ doesn't support higher version of java class file format.The CONSTANT_MethodHandle,CONSTANT_MethodType and CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic of constant pool type missed.Below is my solution to fix the question:

(1) add the type int soot.JastAddJ.BytecodeParser:

```
private static final int CONSTANT_MethodHandle=15;
private static final int CONSTANT_MethodType=16;
private static final int CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic=18;
```

(2) add 3 classes to support the parse:

in the method `parseEntry` of soot.JastAddJ.BytecodeParser,add

CONSTANT_MethodHandle_Info,
CONSTANT_MethodType_Info,
CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic_Info

in the switch case block.

Now,soot can run successfully.

Comment: what are those switch cases are suppose to do? Can you help me please?

Comment: to parse constant pool in java class file,you can learn the java class file format for detail.