# Java compilation error (javax.swing.JComponent)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-indigo

```
package main;
import gameComponent.Game;
import gameComponent.Move;
import gameComponent.Player;
import gameComponent.Tile;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import networking.ClientSideConnection;
import piece.Pawn;
import piece.Piece;
import piece.PieceColor;


public class GameHolderPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private volatile ClientSideConnection self = null;

    private static GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
    public static final Dimension dim = new Dimension(Tile.size,Tile.size);
    public static final Dimension scaledDim = new Dimension(Tile.scaledSize,Tile.scaledSize);
    public static final Border selectedBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
    public static final Border legalMoveBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
    public static final Border nullBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    private Piece selectedPiece = null;
    private int selectedHeldPiece = -1;
    private ArrayList<Move> legalMoveList = new ArrayList<Move>();
    private void clearLegalMoves() {
        for(Move m : legalMoveList) {
            getLabel(m.toTile.x,m.toTile.y).setBorder(nullBorder);
        }
        legalMoveList.clear();
    }

    private static final String[] promotionString = {"Queen", "Knight", "Rook", "Bishop"};
    public JComboBox<String> promotionList = new JComboBox<String>(promotionString);

    private Dimension d = null;

    private JPanel whiteLabelPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel whiteLabel = new JLabel();
    private JPanel blackLabelPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel blackLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel[] xAxisLabel = new JLabel[8];
    private JLabel[] yAxisLabel = new JLabel[8];
    private JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[8][8];
    private ArrayList<JLabel> heldPieces = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    private ArrayList<JLabel> oppHeldPieces = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    private JPanel heldPiecesPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel oppHeldPiecesPanel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane heldPiecesScrollPane = new JScrollPane(heldPiecesPanel);
    private JScrollPane oppHeldPiecesScrollPane = new JScrollPane(oppHeldPiecesPanel);

    private JLabel getLabel(int x, int y) {
        if(pc == PieceColor.W) {
            return label[y][x];
        }
        else {
            return label[7-y][7-x];
        }
    }

    public Game g = null;
    private PieceColor pc = null;//player's or partner's color (ie color of the bottom player)

    public GameHolderPanel(Game g, PieceColor color, ClientSideConnection self, Dimension d) {
        this.g = g;
        this.pc = color;
        this.d = d;
        this.self = self;
        initPanel();
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        float fontSizeScaled = 9.0f;//this needs to be a float because int references the style not fontSize 

        whiteLabel.setText("White");
        whiteLabelPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        if(d != dim) whiteLabel.setFont(whiteLabel.getFont().deriveFont(fontSizeScaled));
        whiteLabelPanel.add(whiteLabel);
        grid.gridwidth = 2;
        if(d != dim) grid.gridwidth = 3;
        grid.gridx = 1;
        grid.gridy = 0;
        add(whiteLabelPanel, grid);

        blackLabel.setText("Black");
        if(d != dim) blackLabel.setFont(blackLabel.getFont().deriveFont(fontSizeScaled));
        blackLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        blackLabelPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        blackLabelPanel.add(blackLabel);
        grid.gridx = 3;
        if(d != dim) grid.gridx = 4;
        grid.gridy = 0;
        add(blackLabelPanel,grid);

        grid.gridwidth = 3;
        grid.gridx = 5;
        grid.gridy = 0;
        add(promotionList, grid);

        for(int i = 0;i<30;i++) {//30 is the maximum number of held pieces: 16P, 4N, 4B, 4R, 2Q
            JLabel newHeldPiece = new JLabel();
            heldPieces.add(newHeldPiece);
            heldPiecesPanel.add(newHeldPiece);

            JLabel newOppHeldPiece = new JLabel();
            oppHeldPieces.add(newOppHeldPiece);
            oppHeldPiecesPanel.add(newOppHeldPiece);
        }
        heldPiecesPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
        heldPiecesPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        ((FlowLayout) heldPiecesPanel.getLayout()).setVgap(0);
        ((FlowLayout) heldPiecesPanel.getLayout()).setHgap(0);

        oppHeldPiecesPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
        oppHeldPiecesPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        ((FlowLayout) oppHeldPiecesPanel.getLayout()).setVgap(0);
        ((FlowLayout) oppHeldPiecesPanel.getLayout()).setHgap(0);

        if(this.g.pW.partner != null) {
            grid.gridx = 1;
            grid.gridy = 1;
            grid.gridwidth = 8;

            oppHeldPiecesScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(grid.gridwidth*d.width, 2*Tile.scaledSize+1));
            oppHeldPiecesScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            oppHeldPiecesScrollPane.setBorder(nullBorder);
            add(oppHeldPiecesScrollPane, grid);

            grid.gridy = 12;
            heldPiecesScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(grid.gridwidth*d.width, 2*Tile.scaledSize+1));
            heldPiecesScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            heldPiecesScrollPane.setBorder(nullBorder);
            add(heldPiecesScrollPane, grid);
        }

        grid.gridwidth = 1;
        initBoard();
    }

    private void initBoard() {
        int addLine = 0;//used to add a line to make room for the heldPieces of the opponent (top of board)
        if(this.g.pW.gameCount > 1) {
            addLine = 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<8;i++) {
            yAxisLabel[i] = new JLabel();
            if(pc == PieceColor.W) {
                yAxisLabel[i].setText(String.valueOf(8-i));
            }
            else {
                yAxisLabel[i].setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
            }
            grid.gridx = 0;
            grid.gridy = i+2+addLine;
            add(yAxisLabel[i],grid);
            for(int j = 0;j<8;j++) {
                label[i][j] = new JLabel();
                label[i][j].setPreferredSize(d);//necessary to prevent the resizing onClick (adds border)
                grid.gridx = j+1;
                grid.gridy = i+2+addLine;
                add(label[i][j],grid);
            }
        }
        grid.gridy = 10+addLine;
        for(int i = 0;i<8;i++) {
            xAxisLabel[i] = new JLabel();
            if(pc == PieceColor.W) {
                xAxisLabel[i].setText(String.valueOf((char) (97+i)));
            }
            else {
                xAxisLabel[i].setText(String.valueOf((char) (97+7-i)));
            }
            grid.gridx = i+1;
            add(xAxisLabel[i],grid);
        }
    }

    public void updateGame(Game g) {
        this.g = g;
        drawBoard();
    }

    public void drawBoard() {
        //display who's turn it is
        if(g.turn.color == PieceColor.W) {
            whiteLabelPanel.setBorder(selectedBorder);
            blackLabelPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
        }
        else {
            whiteLabelPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
            blackLabelPanel.setBorder(selectedBorder);
        }
        //display a winner
        if(g.getWinner() != null) {
            if(g.getWinner().color == PieceColor.W) {
                whiteLabelPanel.setBorder(legalMoveBorder);
                blackLabelPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
            }
            else {
                whiteLabelPanel.setBorder(nullBorder);
                blackLabelPanel.setBorder(legalMoveBorder);
            }
        }

        //draws board
        for(int i = 0;i<8;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<8;j++) {
                getLabel(j,i).setIcon((d == dim) ? g.board[i][j].getIcon() : g.board[i][j].getSmallIcon());
            }
        }

        //draws the pieces held/queued-up by the player
        Player player;
        if(pc == g.pW.color) {
            player = g.pW;
        }
        else {
            player = g.pB;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<heldPieces.size();i++) {
            if(i < player.heldPieces.size()) {
                heldPieces.get(i).setIcon(Tile.getHeldIcon(player.heldPieces.get(i), true));
            }
            else if(i < player.heldPieces.size()+player.queuingPieces.size()) {
                heldPieces.get(i).setIcon(Tile.getHeldIcon(player.queuingPieces.get(i - player.heldPieces.size()), false));
            }
            else {
                heldPieces.get(i).setIcon(null);
            }
        }
        heldPiecesScrollPane.revalidate();

        for(int i = 0;i<oppHeldPieces.size();i++) {
            if(i < player.opponent.heldPieces.size()) {
                oppHeldPieces.get(i).setIcon(Tile.getHeldIcon(player.opponent.heldPieces.get(i), true));
            }
            else if(i < player.opponent.heldPieces.size()+player.opponent.queuingPieces.size()) {
                oppHeldPieces.get(i).setIcon(Tile.getHeldIcon(player.opponent.queuingPieces.get(i - player.opponent.heldPieces.size()), false));
            }
            else {
                oppHeldPieces.get(i).setIcon(null);
            }
        }
        oppHeldPiecesScrollPane.revalidate();
    }

    public void initLabelClicks(final Player p) {
        //for the Player's board
        for(int i = 0;i<8;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<8;j++) {
                final int x = j;
                final int y = i;
                getLabel(x,y).addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        if(g.turn.equals(p)) {
                            if(selectedPiece == null) {
                                if(g.board[y][x].getPiece() != null) {
                                    if(g.board[y][x].getPiece().getColor() == p.color) {
                                        selectedPiece = g.board[y][x].getPiece();
                                        getLabel(x,y).setBorder(selectedBorder);

                                        for(Move m : selectedPiece.getLegalMoves(g, false)) {
                                            legalMoveList.add(m);
                                            getLabel(m.toTile.x, m.toTile.y).setBorder(legalMoveBorder);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if(selectedPiece == g.board[y][x].getPiece()) {
                                clearLegalMoves();
                                getLabel(x,y).setBorder(nullBorder);
                                selectedPiece = null;
                            }
                            else {
                                if(selectedPiece.loc != null) {
                                    Move m = new Move(selectedPiece, g.board[y][x], p);
                                    if(selectedPiece instanceof Pawn && (y == 0 || y == 7)) {
                                        m.moveType = Move.MoveType.getPromotionType(promotionList.getSelectedIndex());
                                    }
                                    if(g.isLegalMove(m)) {
                                        self.send(m);
                                        getLabel(selectedPiece.getX(),selectedPiece.getY()).setBorder(nullBorder);
                                        selectedPiece = null;
                                        clearLegalMoves();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    Move m = new Move(selectedPiece, g.board[y][x], p);
                                    m.moveType = Move.MoveType.PLACEMENT;
                                    if(g.isLegalMove(m)) {
                                        self.send(m);
                                        heldPieces.get(selectedHeldPiece).setBorder(nullBorder);
                                        selectedPiece = null;
                                        clearLegalMoves();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                });
            }
        }

        //for the Player's held pieces
        for(int i = 0;i<30;i++) {//30 is the maximum number of held pieces: 16P, 4N, 4B, 4R, 2Q
            final int x = i;
            heldPieces.get(i).addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    if(g.turn.equals(p) && g.turn.heldPieces.size() > x) {
                        if(selectedPiece == null) {
                            selectedPiece = g.turn.heldPieces.get(x);
                            selectedHeldPiece = x;
                            heldPieces.get(x).setBorder(selectedBorder);

                            for(Move m : selectedPiece.getLegalPlacement(g)) {
                                legalMoveList.add(m);
                                getLabel(m.toTile.x, m.toTile.y).setBorder(legalMoveBorder);
                            }
                        }
                        else if(selectedPiece == g.turn.heldPieces.get(x)) {
                            clearLegalMoves();
                            heldPieces.get(x).setBorder(nullBorder);
                            selectedPiece = null;
                            selectedHeldPiece = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error while running my code "Cannot find the class file for javax.swing.JComponent." in eclipse Indigo. I have netbeans as well but i seem to get JComponent over there, so i'm a bit confused at the moment.

Comment: Post your example code as well as the stacktrace. Also, I strongly suspect this is not just about Java, but about some add-on to Eclipse. Are you making an Android app?

Comment: yes. It's a chess game.

Comment: @jdv Swing, not Android

Comment: Yes, this is part of the Swing API, but you haven't told Eclipse where to find it. Your runtime settings are malformed, or you are not pointing it at a real JDK.

Comment: @jdv how do I fix the settings then?

Comment: I forgot that Eclipse has it's own JDK bundle. My guess is that your Eclipse is not up-to-date. You can try Help -> Check For Updates... However, it is more likely it was never installed correctly in the first place. I'd probably just reinstall Luna.

Comment: @jdv I'm using indigo. I just updated the eclipse today with the java 8 jdk's and jre's. So I should switch to luna? Or should I just re-install my current eclipse all over again?

Comment: Is Java 8 compatible with Indigo? Luna was the first Java 8 supported version, with the previous version requiring a special add-on to support Java 8. Switch the project to Java 7 to test this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150755/how-to-set-eclipse-with-jre-8 Also: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

Comment: @jdv I'll try to see if my current settings go with Luna. Thank You for your advice.

Comment: @jdv JComponent exists since 1.4

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, but Eclipse is often bound to specific Java version for compiling and "intellisense", and I have no idea what happens if you try to target 1.8. The fact is, this looks like a bad install or a bad configuration.

Comment: @jdv Yes, looks strange, but Eclipse works fine with 1.8 in my experience.

Comment: @jdv Your advice has been of great success. You have my thanks once again.

Comment: @m0skit0 because you are using Luna or Kepler SR2 with the plugin, or you are extremely lucky. Otherwise, the build path can be completely fnorded. Please see: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

Comment: @jdv Or simply I don't use any Java 8 features (yet). Like OP.

Comment: @m0ski0t, though, as we've seen, it may not even find 1.4 features because Eclipse uses their own special instrumented JDK package. Eclipse may not find any given class on the build path under these circumstances.

Comment: @m0skit0: not using Java 8 features does not guaranty correct working as Eclipse must be able to handle the JRE’s classes which *do* use Java 8 features.

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing it.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
```

Comment: I tried to but i get an error every time i import it. Keeps telling me "Cannot build project since it's path file is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.swing.JComponent. Fix the build path then try building this project."

Comment: Only JComponent gives you this error? That doesn't make much sense. What do you have in your build path?

Comment: the JARs and class folders in my build path is the JAVA SE 1.7